# Finding percentage of missing days per month

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I need to find percentage based on files<33 per day by month.

in the above scenario there is only one day that is less than 33. so my result should be (1/31)*100

Comment: i am a little unclear on how you would like to access the information, what language and what youve tried thus far?

Answer (score 2):

It is not totally clear what you are trying to here but I think you want something along these lines.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN msgid < 33 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(DISTINCT FILECREATEDATE) * 1.0 --multiply by 1.0 to avoid integer math
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY MONTH(FILECREATEDATE)
```

Comment: If count of msgid less than 33 for a day then I need to calculate percentage based on no. of missing days by total days in that month.                  For example: If there are 5 days that are less than 33 then (5days/31days)*100=16.12%

Comment: That is what this does. The SUM will get the number of rows that are < 33 and divide that by the number of rows for the month. If that isn't what you want then you need to explain your requirements more clearly.